# Is there a built-in function to split a list of objects into two lists based on a condition?

Tags: python

I am writing a function to separate a list based on condition. I am wondering if this is a built-in equivalent in Python.

```py
def separate(seq, separator):
    """Separate the sequence based on falsiness of the separator function
       evaluated on each item   
    """
    true_list = []
    false_list = []
    for item in seq:
        if separator(item):
            true_list.append(item)
        else:
            false_list.append(item)
    return true_list, false_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a proper "built-in" equivalent, but you could do this with two list comprehensions:

```
true_list = [item for item in seq if separator(item)]
false_list = [item for item in seq if not separator(item)]
```

You could also rewrite the second line as:

```
false_list = [item for item in seq if item not in true_list]
```

since they're equivalent. This avoids having to call the `separator` function on each item again, so might be more efficient.

Comment: Depends on the size of the true list the later one is O(N^2) and the complexity of the seperator function.